# Ionic 3 ion-slide in ion-list not working properly

Tags: angular, list, ionic-framework, slide

My slide is not working anymore when I put it in ion-list. The reason I put it in there is because I'm using infinite scroll and if I put a slide outside the list it doesn't scroll properly. Is there a way to get the slide working in ion-list?

```
<ion-list no-lines style="width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;" [hidden]="artArray.length == 0" [virtualScroll]="artArray" approxItemHeight="40px">

<div >
    <ion-slides autoplay="3000" loop="true" speed="400" style="height:120px;" pager="true">
        <ion-slide>
            <img src="assets/p1.png" />
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <img src="assets/p2.png" />
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <img src="assets/p3.png" />
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</div>

    <ion-item *virtualItem="let item;let i=index" no-padding style="border-bottom:solid #eeeeee 1px;height:120px;" (click)="pushArtdetailsPage($event, item)"
     [ngClass]="{'firstitem': i==0 }" >

        <div id="lstimg" style="width:120px;height:120px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;background-color:#f8f8f8;">
            <img src="{{ item.art_pic1 }}" width="120px" height="100px" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 10px;">
            <!--<ion-img width="120px" height="100px" src="{{ item.art_pic1 }}" [cache]="true" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 10px;"></ion-img>-->
            <!--<virtual-ion-img width="100px" height="100px" [src]=" item.art_pic1"></virtual-ion-img>-->
        </div>
        <h6 ion-text color="dark" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:130px;font-weight:bold;">{{ item.art_name }}</h6>
        <h6 ion-text style="position:absolute;left:130px;top:30px;font-weight:bold;font-size:0.9em;color:gray;" *ngIf="item.art_is_shop != 1">{{ item.art_seller }}</h6>
        <h6 ion-text color="primary" style="position:absolute;left:130px;top:30px;font-weight:bold;font-size:0.9em;" *ngIf="item.art_is_shop == 1">{{ item.art_seller }}</h6>
        <h6 ion-text color="mygray" style="position:absolute;left:130px;top:50px;font-size:0.9em;font-weight:bold;color:gray;"><span ion-text color="mygary">{{ item.art_price }}</span> fcfa</h6>
        <h6 *ngIf="item.art_old_price !=0" ion-text color="mygray" style="background-color: #fae6ee;padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;font-size:0.7em;position:absolute;left:130px;top:75px;text-decoration:line-through;font-weight:bold;">{{ item.art_old_price }} fcfa</h6>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but have you try changing the `div` encapsulating the slide into an `item` of the `list`?

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
       <ion-slides>
         <ion-slide>
         </ion-slide/>
       </ion-slides>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *virtualItem="let item;let i=index">
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

But not sure it gonna solve your original proble `it doesn't scroll properly`.

Btw. what do you mean with `it doesn't scroll properly`?

Without using `virtualScroll` for example with a `ngFor` does it scroll properly?

Have you try to decontruct the `css` properties of the page with the Chrome debugger to see if a css attribute would have this side effect?

Comment: it doesn't even scroll unless i do it manualy with my fingers.it stays static . but sometimes the pager changes once thats it. yes i tried to wrap it in an item same behaviour, no i haven't tried ngfor yet but i need to use virtual scroll

Comment: in that case I would then try to desconstruct the page. Add components and css from scratch, one after the other, till you find what it the reason of the blocking

Comment: if i use the slides outside the list, the who;e content doesnt scroll properly it leaves blabk space on top and bottom maybe because to generate virtual item the virtual scroll needs the whole page height. thanks i will try to do what you suggested me

Comment: Another way of checking it is also maybe trying to reproduce the problem in a super minimal new project, sometimes it helps to find out what doesn't work or to find out if there is a bug somewhere...good luck!